# positive lookahead WITH counting condition

Tags: regex

I was looking for this whole day and only found that the regex:

```
/.+?(?=\}\s*,)/
```

It means: *match any characters as few as possible until `}(any whitespace),` is found, without counting the `}(any whitespace),`*.

However, I need it to match WITH counting the `}(any whitespace),`.

My whole regexp looks like:

```
\s*MT_(F[0-9A-Z]+)\s+\{\s+@Override[\s\S]*?(?=\}\s*,)
```

and should select:

```
  MT_F102 {
        @Override
        public F102 func1() {
        }

        @Override
        public String func2() {
        }
    }
```

Please advise me what to do.

Thank you! :)

Comment: So, add the `}\s*,` to the consuming pattern, remove the lookahead - `/.+?}\s*,/`

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for correct answer. it works fine. I do not know how to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @MilanChe I posted the answer. Next time, to let the user know of your feedback, add `@` before the username to send notification

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the lookahead and use

```
/.+?}\s*,/
```

**Details**

- `.+?` - any 1 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `}` - a `}` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `,` - a comma.

Implementing it in your bigger regex:

```
/\s*MT_(F[0-9A-Z]+)\s+\{\s+@Override[\s\S]*?\}\s*,/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0xN8lI/1).